# Fortify:Target class [password.confirm] does not exist

Tags: laravel, authentication, fortify

I am implementing with fortify the "two factor authentication" as the first step to make a POST call to the route:  /user/two-factor-authentication

I created the following form:

```
@if (session('status') != 'two-factor-authentication-enabled')
    <div class="mb-4 font-medium text-sm text-green-600">
        Two factor authentication has been enabled.
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('two-factor.enable')}}">
            @csrf

            <button>
                Submit
            </button>
        </form>

    </div>
@endif
```

After pressing the button I get the following error: Illuminate \ Contracts \ Container \ BindingResolutionException
Target class [password.confirm] does not exist.

Comment: Please add the controller codes. It seems the bug is in there.

Comment: You need to put the controller code also here, not view

Comment: it is the controller of Fortify specifically TwoFactorAuthenticationController, but the problem is not in the controller it is that the middleware stops it one of three: password.confirm, App \ Http \ Middleware \ Authenticate: web, web. I am logged into my system

Comment: to have double authentication with fortify you have to enable it and then call in POST this route / user / two-factor-authentication that goes to use the controller of the fortify package, it should make me the redirect, but it gives me that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
In your app/http/kernel.php add the following command

```
'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class
```